# Sequentially searching two dimensional char array

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm working with the following:

```
private char [][] board;
<various lines of code>

//Sequential searching for an index that has yet to be
//changed from the default char character 
for(int i = 0; i< board.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j>board[i].length; j++)
        {
            //Here I get the error "incomparable types: char and char[]
            if('\u0000' == board[j])
                    System.out.println("Game unfinished.");                  
        }
     //Here I get the error "incomparable types: char and char[]
     if('\u0000' == board[j])
                 System.out.println("Game unfinished.");
    }
    else return 'T';
```

In essence, I want to traverse the array, doing either one of two things:

1. If all array indexes are occupied by either 'X' or 'O' then return 'T' OR
2. If an array index is found with '\u0000' do:

   System.out.print("Game unfinished.");

Comment: `board[i]` is of type `char(*)[]` not `char`

Comment: @bb94 I'm not speaking from language perspective, but from perspective of underlying pointer mechanics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to add a null check, just in case. Then, fix the for condition as @libik indicated. Finally, reference the cell by its i and j indecies. e.g:

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        //Always check for nulls, unless you're 100% certain of the data
        if (board[i] != null) {   
          for(int j = 0; j < board[i][j].length; j++) {
              //Here I get the error "incomparable types: char and char[]
              if('\u0000' == board[i][j]) {  
                      System.out.println("Game unfinished.");                  
              }
          }
 }
```

Regarding the second if statement and the return 'T', these don't make sense as they stand. Did you want to return 'T' if no '\u0000' chars where found in the array? If so, create a boolean flag, initialize it to false, then set it on the else condition of the if statement above. Outside of the loop, add a second if to see if the flag was ever set and return 'T'.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes.

First change `j>board[i].length` to `j<board[i].length`

Then you have to compare char to char, in 2D char, you have to specify both dimension, to get char, specify only one means you only specify row or column of chars (thus it is array of char).

Comparing should look like this : `if('\u0000' == board[i][j])`

Comment: Actually `board[i][j]`. And remove the second occurrence.

Comment: Thanks. Second occurrence of what exactly?

Comment: I still do not understand what do you want me to do, sry :)

Comment: * facepalm * You have two instances of the same piece of code. Remove the latter.